# Image uploaded to S3 is corrupted

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, axios, blob, digital-ocean

I'm trying to upload a blob created by cropperjs to DigitalOcean spaces.

To do that I'm using a pre-signed URL, and I use Axios to do a put request.

The issue is that if I try to open the uploaded image, I can't, it is corrupt.

Before doing the put request I used an npm package to download the blob to see if it was corrupted before the request.
But it's not.
So it must be an issue with the request but I don't know what.

Here is the code I use to upload the image.

```
this.$refs.cropper
            .getCroppedCanvas({
              width: 500,
              height: 500
            })
            .toBlob(blob => {
              var formData = new FormData();
              blob.lastModifiedDate = new Date();
              blob.name = response.data.id + ".png";
              formData.append(response.data.id, blob, blob.name);
              axios
                .put(response.data.url, formData, {
                  header: {
                    "Content-Type": blob.type
                  }
                })
                .then(() => {
                  console.log("uploaded");
                })
                .catch(err => {
                  console.log(err);
                });
            });
```

`response.data.url` is the pre-signed URL.

Also on DigitalOcean the Content-Type of my file is
`multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryDYMUYTIXMb7817EY`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a fix.

```
axios
    .put(response.data.url, blob, {
        header: {
            "Content-Type": blob.type
        }
    })
    .then(() => {
        console.log("uploaded");
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

Instead of using `formData` I just used `blob`